# Query regarding TLS encryption

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, encryption

I have made two J2EE applications where in one servlet in ProjectX is performing a sendRedirect to another servlet of ProjectY via https protocol.

Code is something like

```
 response.sendRedirect("https://ip:8443/ProjectY/servletY?id=123");
```

In ProjectY,

SerletY is having code as

```
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.print("Passed id is ID = " + request.getParameter("id"));
```

My Query is ,

since the data sent accross the network is ideally encrypted when using https, why am I able to see the url of the browser after redirecting to ServletY as

"https://ip:8443/ProjectY/servletY?id=123"

I have hidden the parameter using POST method , but my question is , is it actually encrypting data while sending from ProjectX(which was in http) to ProjectY (which is https call) ?

Thanks for you support.!!!

Comment: The encryption is between the browser and your server, so both your browser and your server have access to the unencrypted information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's happening

There is no `POST` request involved.

1. The user opens ProjectX' site in the browser
2. It will respond with a `HTTP 302` response because of your `response.sendRedirect`.
3. The user's browser will take the `Location` of the response and open it
4. Thus the user's browser establishes an TLS connection to `ip:8443`
5. After the TLS channel is opened, it will send a `GET /ProjectY/servletY?id=123 HTTP/1.1`
6. ProjectY will respond over the secure TLS channel.

### Observations

- If you call ProjectX in step 1 via plain `HTTP`, then the `302` response won't be encrypted and everybody who has access to your connection can see the `id`.
- The user's browser will always see the `id` because it needs to follow the redirect in step 3.
- The user will see the `id` in the address bar because the browser will show its new location.
- When calling ProjectY, the `id` is protected because it is only sent via the TLS channel.

Comment: Thanks Scolytus, so we can conclude that the data is still getting encrypted before being transferred. But we will be able to see it on the client browser because it is requesting that URL, post which the parameters will be encrypted before sending and decrypted after receiving by ServetY.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge.!!

Comment: @ArghoChatterjee keep in mind that it is **not** encrypted from ProjectX to your user's browser. But from the browser to ProjectY it's encrypted, yes.